# What is the purpose of the system() function if I already have access to the system?

Tags: c, ssh, system

If I ran the ssh command and logged into a server, would there be any reason to have code call system() since I can run it myself?

Edit: The code I have would be written in C

Comment: This is a bit like asking "is there any reason for the `+` operator, because I can calculate it myself?".

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure if calling the system function did anything else.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but whatever the question, `system` is almost certainly the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

system call will execute the program (with parameters) that you want. A system() call invokes a shell. So from inside of a C program, if you want to remove a file, you can invoke system with `"rm filename"` as argument (this is just a use case - definitely not how you'd like to delete a file from a C program)
You should use system() only when you know what you are doing. If a user input is any part of the argument to the system call, you should make sure you are sanitizing your input lest you are opening yourself to command injections.

An example of a command injections with system call is [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection)

Alternatives to system are popen and obviously fork+exec.